# Android: Private message app

Tags: android, message, microblogging

I want to develop an app which broadcast messages which can be viewed only through this app. so, it can be used by teachers to broadcast instructions which students with this app (or a reciever app) can access. Can anyone help me with ideas to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to have a look on the http://www.parse.com API to implement User access and Push easily. It's really awesome !

You can create a free account and use it until 1 000 000 request by month, which can be enough I think...

Comment: Seems great!but got an error on test.

Comment: 05-26 18:05:27.128: E/AndroidRuntime(4129): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.ParseUser
05-26 18:05:27.128: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):  at com.parse.starter.ParseApplication.onCreate(ParseApplication.java:20)
05-26 18:05:27.128: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766437/android-parse-com-parseobject-classnotfound-error

Answer (score 0):

You need to have external server which will store the messages. Your client app will then connect to the server and pull new data.

Personally, I'd go with PHP website for the server, as it can be implemented quickly.

Comment: yeah, thats what i am thinking, but my question is what is the best way to implement it?