# android: Parse.com Parseobject classnotfound error

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, parse-platform

I use Parse.com's library in my android application and i get the following error.

> 05-26 18:43:31.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4759): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-26 18:43:31.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.ParseObject 05-26
>   18:43:31.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     at
>   com.parse.starter.ParseStarterProjectActivity.onCreate(ParseStarterProjectActivity.java:14)
>   05-26 18:43:31.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   05-26 18:43:31.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
>   05-26 18:43:31.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
>   05-26 18:43:31.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123) 05-26
>   18:43:31.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
>   05-26 18:43:31.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 05-26
>   18:43:31.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 05-26 18:43:31.838:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4759):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835) 05-26
>   18:43:31.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 05-26
>   18:43:31.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 05-26 18:43:31.838:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4759):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
>   05-26 18:43:31.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605) 05-26
>   18:43:31.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Please help me solve this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716

Comment: still the same. in fact i used their sample project. in which libs folder already exists.

Comment: How are you importing the jar ? `libs` folder ? `external jar` ?

Comment: libs folder and there are no errors before running. only runtime exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Parse and Android for some crazy reason after checking the SDK versions i noticed there was no Target SDK version, but there was one for Min SDK version. I just added the target SDK version ( 8 in this case ) to match the Min version and it works. I guess Parse checks for target SDK version or something.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may helpful for you.

Open project's properties.

Click on java build path.

Click order and export tab and click on parse jar file to check this.

And build and clean your project then run.